# How to normalize a slope?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, graphing-functions, average

Say I have two slopes and two averages for a sample:

$m=4{,}000$ dollars/day, average $a=50{,}000$

$n=80{,}000$ dollars/day, average $b=700{,}000$

Graphically, $n$ is very ‘steep’ compared to $m$. But I know that $n$ is not very steep relative to it's average size ($b=700{,}000$). Is there a way that I could get a ‘percent slope’, so that I could compare the slopes of these two values relative to the average size?

Comment: Sure, and it can be done exactly how you're thinking: you can say, for instance, that '$n$'s rate of change is 14% of its average value', while '$m$'s rate of change is 8% of its average value'.  (Note that $n$ is still 'steeper' than $m$ compared to its average!)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply express this relative change as a fraction, namely

$$\frac ma=0.080=8.0\%\qquad\text{resp.}\qquad\frac nb\approx0.114=11.4\%$$